# Bluetooth GPS on iPad

Tags: ipad, gps

I have purchase a iPad (non 3g model) and have also recently started using an application called Foreflight for my personal flight planning while getting my private pilots license.  I would love to be able to get a fix on my location - is there any way I can use a bluetooth GPS receiver with this application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen and used GPS receivers that connect to the host via bluetooth, on Windows Mobile phones.  I'm not sure about on an iPad.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the answer to your question is no. According to the [specs page](http://www.apple.com/ipad/specs/), the only way the WiFi model can get Location services is via WiFi geolocation. I've never heard of a device using bluetooth to get a location fix. That'd be cool though.

Answer (score 0):

you can, you need to jailbreak your ipad and go to cydia and download roqybt, it costs like 10bucks or something. it enables you to use your bluetooth enabled gps device with the ipads bluetooth chip, so you get a gps fix and can use it for navigation.